# Disable Audio device?

Tags: root-access, audio, camera, xposed-framework

I bought a phone in Japan(Huawei P10) and in Japan by law the camera app has to make shutter sound. But, when I am back to my country, I want to disable that, because it's obviously annoying.

Do not disturb doesn't work. I already renamed the shutter sound files, which disabled it in apps like snapchat and whatsapp, but the stock camera app still makes a sound.
So I thought, that I maybe could disable the audio device and enable it again if I need it. Do you know how?

- I have magisk and xposed if that helps.
- I want to use the stock camera app and an open-source way (especially with an "accessibility service"-app)